# selenium python webdriver.Firefox() fails to connect

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying something very simple with selenium in python

```
from selenium import webdriver
q = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and I get this response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/rcortes/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/home/rcortes/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/rcortes/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/home/rcortes/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/rcortes/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'\n\n\n\nNotification: Gateway Timeout\n\n\nbody {\n  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n  font-size: 14px;\n  color:#333333;\n  background-color: #ffffff;\n}\nh1 {\n  font-size: 18px;\n  font-weight: bold;\n  text-decoration: none;\n  padding-top: 0px;\n  color: #2970A6;\n}\na:link {\n    color: #2970A6;\n  text-decoration: none;\n}\na:hover {\n    color: #2970A6;\n  text-decoration: underline;\n}\np.buttonlink {\n  margin-bottom: 24px;\n}\n.copyright {\n  font-size: 12px;\n  color: #666666;\n  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;\n\n}\n.details {\n  font-size: 14px;\n  color: #969696;\n  border: none;\n  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;\n  margin: 0px 10px 10px 35px;\n}\n\n.shadow {\n  border: 3px solid #9f9f9f;\n  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;\n  margin: 10px 35px 0px 30px;\n  background-color: #ffffff;\n  width: 600px;\n\n  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;\n  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;\n  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;\n  /* For IE 8 */\n  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color=\'cccccc\')";\n  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */\n  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color=\'cccccc\');\n}\n.logo {\n  border: none;\n  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;\n}\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\nThis Page Cannot Be Displayed\n\n\n\nThe system cannot communicate with the external server ( 127.0.0.1 ).\nThe Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be\nunreachable because of network problems.\n\n\n\nPlease check the spelling of the Internet address entered.\nIf it is correct, try this request later.\n\n\n\n\n\nIf you have questions, please contact\nyour corporate network administrator \nand provide the codes shown below.\n\n\n\n\n\nDate: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 17:48:26 PDT
\nUsername: 
\nSource IP: 10.130.49.59
\nURL: POST http://127.0.0.1/hub/session
\nCategory: Infrastructure and Content Delivery Networks
\nReason: UNKNOWN
\nNotification: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT\n\n\n'
```

i am trying to follow these simple directions http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp . Please help

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: yes, im just trying to start the Firefox webdriver with the simplest configuration. According to the docs this should work.

Cheers

Comment: And your wifi/ether is otherwise working?

Comment: yeah. Im able to connect to everything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Even though firefox had disabled proxies for intranet sites, I believe selenium was still trying to connect to the server through the proxy. I just disabled the proxy and it worked.